# How to add new elements based on attribute values using xslt

Tags: xslt, transformation

I want to use `xslt` to transform this `xml` input,

```
 <node1 name="n1">
    <node2 name="n2_X1" transform="keep_me"/>
    <node2 name="n2_X2" transform="change_key1"/>
    <node2 name="n2_X3" transform="change_key2"/>
    <node2 name="n2_X4" transform="keep_me"/>
 </node1>
```

to an output `xml` that look like this,

```
<node1 name="n1">
    <node2 name="n2_X1" transform="keep_me"/>
    <node2 name="n2_X2" transform="change_key1"/>
    <node2 name="n2_X3" transform="change_key2"/>
    <node2 name="n2_X4" transform="keep_me"/>
    <node3 type="join_tables">
        <node4 name="new_name1_corresponding_to_change_key1"/>
        <node4 name="new_name2_corresponding_to_change_key2"/>
    </node3>
</node1>
```

Basically if my `xlst` code sees `transform="change_key1"`, I want it create a new node called `node3` (if not created yet), and add an attribute `type="join_tables"`, then create a new node `node4`, and add an attribute `name="new_name1_corresponding_to_change_key1"`.

I can use `xslt` to change existing attribute values but have difficulty adding `node3` and `node4`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems rather trivial:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="node1">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*|*"/>
        <xsl:variable name="join_tables" select="node2[starts-with(@transform, 'change_key')]" />
        <xsl:if test="$join_tables">
            <node3 type="join_tables">
                <xsl:for-each select="$join_tables">
                    <node4 name="new_name{position()}_corresponding_to_{@transform}"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </node3>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```